# WCF служба, wsDualHttpBinding и 80 порт

Tags: c#, .net, http, wcf

При подключении к WCF службе вылетает `exception`, хотя в `app.config` конфиг явно указан не 80 порт:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException' occurred in
>   System.ServiceModel.dll
>
> Additional information: HTTP could not register URL
>   http://+:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/c3e45f68-abf2-4847-95a6-cfd3f512fc54/
>   because TCP port 80 is being used by another application.

Самое странное, что на одном ПК вылетает `exception`, а на другом нет. В чем может быть проблема?

`app.config` клиента :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsDualHttpBinding>
                <binding name="wsEndpoint" />
            </wsDualHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:50055/Service" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="wsEndpoint" contract="ServiceReference1.IChatServerService"
                name="wsEndpoint">
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

`app.config` сервер:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour0" name="Services.Concrete.ChatServerService">
        <endpoint address="ws" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" name="wsEndpoint"
          contract="Services.Abstracts.IChatServerService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mexEndpoint"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:50055/Service/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour0">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Внутри службы с 80 портом никаких манипуляций не производится?

Comment: @Streletz, нет, не производится.

Comment: Добавлю к этому: посмотреть кто захватил порт 80 можно так: `netstat -anb > ports.txt`. В моём случае это был Skype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы используете [`wsDualHttpBinding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms731821(v=vs.110).aspx). В этом режиме клиент прослушивает некоторый адрес, где ожидает ответы от сервера. И вот этот-то адрес, который в конфиге вы не задавали, и находится на 80м порту по умолчанию!

Используйте атрибут `clientBaseAddress` для указания обратного адреса на клиенте:

```
        <wsDualHttpBinding>
            <binding name="wsEndpoint" clientBaseAddress="http://localhost:50055/Client/" />
        </wsDualHttpBinding>
```

Либо используйте другие способы соединения. Так, `netTcpBinding` - и без обратного адреса умеет передавать сообщения в обе стороны. Еще где-то в WCF есть поддержка веб-сокетов, но я не помню где.

---

Теперь почему может быть занят 80й порт на некоторых компьютерах. Скорее всего, это Skype, который использует этот порт по умолчанию:

[image: скриншот скайпа]

Но, конечно же, не следует отбрасывать и вариант обычного веб-сервера, Apache, Nginx или Tomcat. А вот IIS с WCF "дружат", поскольку используют один и тот же HTTP.SYS.